# Content types hiding and permission

Tags: permissions, content-type, plone, genericsetup

I'd like to disable/hide some content types site-wide so that only Administrators can add them. What would be the best practice to do it? Does GenericSetup provide any XML for such a task or do I need to create a custom import step?

Comment: Thanks for the question Mikko - I have a few sites I'd love to do that on, too

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't this just be a question of assigning the "Add [Content type]" permission to the appropriate role?  (Or creating such a permission if your content type assumes use of the general "add content" permission?)

Comment: This answer does not answer to how part :)